# Receiving "-[__NSCFNumber buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error when tapping UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a view controller OptionsViewController class with multiple planned NIBs. I'm trying to make the first NIB, ThreeOptionsViewController.xib. The interface file has multiple buttons that, when clicked, should call a method buttonPressed in OptionsViewController. My buttonPressed function is simple:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"buttonPressed");
}
```

However, when I tap a button, I receive the following error:

```
2015-03-18 01:12:52.972 Yoyo[1961:29189] -[__NSCFNumber buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe1052670f0
2015-03-18 01:12:52.980 Yoyo[1961:29189] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe1052670f0'
```

I understand that this error usually occurs when the program looks for the method in the wrong class, or when there's a misspelling. But the File's Owner Class name for ThreeOptionsViewController.xib is set to OptionsViewController. And I connected the buttons by specifically control-dragging from a button to buttonPressed. I know that the NIB is really connected to OptionsViewController because I have IBOutlets of the buttons, and the buttons are properly modified based on the code of OptionsViewController.

I also tried adding the action programmatically by removing the connections in the XIB file and adding the following line to OptionsViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
[_button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

But I get the same error. I don't understand why the program isn't looking for buttonPressed in ObjectsViewController, and what in the world __NSCFNumber has to do with any of this. The full output is:

```
2015-03-18 01:12:52.972 Yoyo[1961:29189] -[__NSCFNumber buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe1052670f0
2015-03-18 01:12:52.980 Yoyo[1961:29189] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe1052670f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f7cba75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f464bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f7d2d1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f72a9dc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f72a578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010fbbca22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010fcc3e50 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010fcc321f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ff6ae80 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 9487
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010fc02856 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010fc03483 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010fbcffb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010fbdd227 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17700
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010fbb823c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f700c91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f6f6b5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f6f6194 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f6f5bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011135da58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010fbbb580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    20  Yoyo                                0x000000010da84a63 main + 115
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111965145 start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: How do you create button1, and do you assign any value to it?

Comment: It is created from the NIB and accessed with a standard IBOutlet. I figured out my issue though. It was, as someone else could have guessed, a case of poor memory management. The ViewController that contains buttonPressed was initialized by a parent ViewController, but it wasn't retained, as far as I can tell. I fixed it by assigning the initialized ViewController to a strong @property created in the .h file of the parent ViewController.